# In flatpickr, how to set default start & end time

Tags: reactjs, flatpickr

I have a date+time range picker using [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/) (like https://jsfiddle.net/wxLb6m4n/)

```
<Flatpickr options = {{
    mode: 'range',
    enableTime: true,
    defaultHour: 8,
}} />
```

There is only one option for defaultHour that would set both start & end time.

How do I set the **start** time to be **8am**, and **end** time to be **5pm** by default?

(I am using this in [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) in React, if that matters)